# How to update state on button click

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting the "id" of an element and trying to set that as a state by clicking a button. i couldn't make it. following is my code.

```
sendJobId = () => {
    const id = $('.modal').attr('id');
    this.setState=({jobId:this.id})

}
```

the onclick is on the following

```
<Link to={`/employerprofile`} onClick={this.sendJobId}>visit employer profile</Link>
```

Comment: Don't use jQuery with React. It's unnecessary. You can get the id by setting a `ref` on the element in question.

Comment: Could you include your entire component? You shouldn't have to use jQuery for this.

Comment: sorry its too long ` <div className="modal fade show" id={joblist.id} tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">`

Comment: @Chris can you tell me how to use ref and get the value to setState

Answer (score 0):

Remove = between this.setState and object. setState is a function.

```
sendJobId = () => {
    const id = $('.modal').attr('id');
    this.setState({jobId:this.id});

}
```

Comment: but i dont have an "=" in that

Comment: I can see =  in your question.

Comment: There can also be a case that when you are clicking you would be redirected to another page and this function wouldn't be called.

Comment: sorry it was a type error... i dont have it in my code :)... but how can i update the state?

Comment: Well you have 'const id' then use 'this.id' in the setState() call. Try it like: this.setState({ jobId: id });

Comment: getting this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'jobId' of null"

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question, but the context of your problem. In other words, why you want to fetch the id and so on. That being said, here is how to properly get the id and set the state.

In your constructor, add:

```
this.someRef = React.createRef();
```

Then add the ref to the element you are interested in:

```
<div ref={this.someRef} className="modal fade show" id={joblist.id} tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Now that you have a direct reference of that `div` in the DOM, you can set the state:

```
sendJobId = () => {
  const {id} = this.someRef.current; // Destructuring syntax, fyi
  this.setState({jobId: id});
}
```

Comment: i tried this ` <div className="modal fade show" id={joblist.id} ref="jobid" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">` and called it as `console.log(this.refs.jobid.id);` ... this being a mapped component im only getting the last id... i need the id for which i click

Comment: the id's are dynamic and i need the id on which i click